# How to remove duplicates from an aggregation result that uses sorted full text search in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I would like to preform a full text search on records containing both text and an identifier.  The identifier is not unique.  The search should find all identifiers w/o duplicates for a given text search.  In addition, the list should be sorted by text match score  I have tried to use $group to remove the duplicates, but it explicitly states it does not maintain order and in fact I get different orderings of the identifiers across different runs.  I have following script.

```js
use text
db.dropDatabase()
use text
db.annotations.insertMany([
  { id : "1", desc:"one two three four five six seven eigth nine" },
  { id : "1", desc:"two three four five six seven eigth nine" },
  { id : "1", desc:"three four five six seven eigth nine" },
  { id : "2", desc:"four five six seven eigth nine" },
  { id : "2", desc:"five six seven eigth nine" },
  { id : "2", desc:"six seven eigth nine" },
  { id : "3", desc:"seven eigth nine" },
  { id : "3", desc:"eigth nine" },
  { id : "3", desc:"nine" },
])
db.annotations.createIndex( { desc: "text" } )
var query =  [
  { $match : { $text : { $search : "nine" } } }
   , { $project : { id : 1 } }
   , { $sort : { score : { $meta :"textScore" } }}
//   , { $group : { _id : "$id" } }
//   , { $limit : 2 }
//   , { $skip : 1 }
];
printjson(query)
db.annotations.aggregate(query).forEach(printjson)
```

which, as expected produces,

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc8"), "id" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc7"), "id" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc6"), "id" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc5"), "id" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc4"), "id" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc3"), "id" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc2"), "id" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc1"), "id" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc0"), "id" : "1" }
```

What I'm hoping for is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc8"), "id" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc5"), "id" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("649ef1f4cd3347bd47c85fc2"), "id" : "1" }
```

And then I'd like to also be able to use $limit and $skip on this result.

I'm using Mongodb 5.0.7 on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it explicitly states it does not maintain order

It does not maintain ordering in its *output*, but it respects the ordering passed to it as input. You can see a reference to that, for example, in the [documentation for the `$first` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#behavior) (emphasis added):

> NOTE
>
> Although the `$sort` stage passes ordered documents as input to the `$group` and `$setWindowFields` stages, those stages are not guaranteed to maintain the sort order **in their own output**.

Therefore I think you're looking for basically what you started writing, which is something similar to the following:

```
db.annotations.aggregate([
   { '$match': { '$text': { '$search': 'nine' } } },
   { '$addFields': { score: { '$meta': 'textScore' } } },
   { '$sort': { score: -1 } },
   { '$group': { _id: '$id', first_id: { '$first': '$_id' } } }
]);
```

With your data:

```
> db.annotations.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9ee"),
    id: '1',
    desc: 'one two three four five six seven eigth nine'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9ef"),
    id: '1',
    desc: 'two three four five six seven eigth nine'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f0"),
    id: '1',
    desc: 'three four five six seven eigth nine'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f1"),
    id: '2',
    desc: 'four five six seven eigth nine'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f2"),
    id: '2',
    desc: 'five six seven eigth nine'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f3"),
    id: '2',
    desc: 'six seven eigth nine'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f4"),
    id: '3',
    desc: 'seven eigth nine'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f5"),
    id: '3',
    desc: 'eigth nine'
  },
  { _id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f6"), id: '3', desc: 'nine' }
]
> db.annotations.aggregate([
...    { '$match': { '$text': { '$search': 'nine' } } },
...    { '$addFields': { score: { '$meta': 'textScore' } } },
...    { '$sort': { score: -1 } },
...    { '$group': { _id: '$id', first_id: { '$first': '$_id' } } }
... ]);
[
  { _id: '2', first_id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f3") },
  { _id: '3', first_id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f6") },
  { _id: '1', first_id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f0") }
]
```

I think that the pipeline could be slightly simpler without the `$addFields` but I seemed to be getting some confusing error message when trying to compute the field to sort on inline and it seemed like a distraction to the main point.

This aggregation doesn't *remove* the other documents, just identifies which are the top ones that presumably you are looking to keep.

#### Edit

If you wish to maintain the final ordering based on the txt score, this modified pipeline achieves that:

```
[
  { '$match': { '$text': { '$search': 'nine' } } },
  { '$addFields': { score: { '$meta': 'textScore' } } },
  { '$sort': { score: -1 } },
  {
    '$group': {
      _id: '$id',
      first_id: { '$first': '$_id' },
      top_score: { '$first': '$score' }
    }
  },
  { '$sort': { top_score: -1 } }
]
```

Running it yields:

```
> db.annotations.aggregate([
  { '$match': { '$text': { '$search': 'nine' } } },
  { '$addFields': { score: { '$meta': 'textScore' } } },
  { '$sort': { score: -1 } },
  {
    '$group': {
      _id: '$id',
      first_id: { '$first': '$_id' },
      top_score: { '$first': '$score' }
    }
  },
  { '$sort': { top_score: -1 } }
]);
[
  {
    _id: '3',
    first_id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f6"),
    top_score: 1.1
  },
  {
    _id: '2',
    first_id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f3"),
    top_score: 0.625
  },
  {
    _id: '1',
    first_id: ObjectId("649ef9c074ed76e5c703d9f0"),
    top_score: 0.5714285714285714
  }
]
```

You can `$project` out the `top_score` field if you don't want it to show up in the output.

Comment: Thanks, but the results are not in the correct order (i.e. 3,2,1).

Comment: Was that part of the requirements? The final output needs to be sorted on `id`? If so, that's a very easy fix (append a `$sort` stage at the end which I can add to the answer after you confirm/clarify). I was mostly under the impression that you wanted each set of documents in a group sorted based on score prior to collapsing them

Comment: Or do you want the final output ordered based on the original text scoring as well, which coincidentally matches the descending id order from your sample documents?

Comment: Yes to your last post, the sorting should be by text match score, which happens to be in descending id order.

Comment: Great - thanks for the confirmation. I went ahead and added that to my answer in the edit yesterday, give that a try.